# Using python to implement the tail recursion function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion, tail-recursion

For a function `p(0) = 10000, p(n) = p(n-1) + 0.02*p(n-1)`,

the code should be like this:

```
def p(n,v=10000):
    if n == 0:
         return v
    else:
         return p(n-1,1.02*v)
```

But if `p(0) = 10000, p(n) = p(n-1) + 10**(n-1)`,

then how to write this tail recursion?

Comment: Note that python does not have tail call optimization, so forcing code to be tail recursive is generally a waste. Do you really need this restriction (e.g. for an exercise) or do you just need *any* recursive solution?

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem

```
def p(n):
    if n==0:
        return 10000
    else: # n!=0
        return p(n-1) + 0.02 * p(n-1)
    
print(p(0)) # The result is 10000
print(p(1)) # The result is 10200.0
```

the first if will be the base of the recursion which is p(0)
and the else will be the recursion function

Comment: It works, while I want to write tail recursion. Anyway, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the tali recursion code for the function that you wanted

```
def p(n,v=10000):
    if n == 0:
         return v
    else:
         return p(n-1, v + 10**(n-1))
```

Here, we use the v as the value from the previous function recursion call, and then add the 10**(n-1) to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. you already have tail recursion with the `if n == 0: return v`. You just need to rework the non constant return value. Try this:

```
def p(n, v=10000):
    if n == 0:
         return v
    else:
         return p(n - 1, v) + 10**(n - 1)
```

Comment: I really appreciate it.